# Read two files and substitute a pattern in one file with data from the other file

Tags: regex, perl, substitution

I am running a perl script, which takes data from first file, match a pattern in second file, and replace with the data (first file) when match is found.

When I run my script, no replacement occurs in the second file. I am working on windows.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my ($value1,$value2);
open(file1, "data1.txt") or die "Cannot open file.\n";
open(file2, "data2.txt") or die "Cannot open file.\n";

while (<file1>) {
    $value1 = $_;
    chomp($value1);
    my @parts = split(/ +/, $value1); 
    $value2 = <file2>;

    $value2 =~ s/ threshold1/ $parts[0]/;
    $value2 =~ s/ threshold2/ $parts[1]/;
    $value2 =~ s/ threshold3/ $parts[1]/;
    }
close(file1);
close(file2);
```

**File 1**

```
10
20
30
```

**File 2**

```
a=1 b=2 c=3
d=4 e=5 f=6
g = threshold1 h=7 i=8
lines
lines
j= 9 k=11 
l = threshold2
lines
lines
m = threshold3
lines
lines
```

I need to replace threshold1 , threshold2, threshold3 in second file, with values from the first file.

Comment: You never save value2!

Comment: Can you give a clear example of what it is you're trying to do?

Comment: I am taking data from  file1 for eg. 10 and place it in second file after matching a pattern for eg threshold1 , and put it there. so my file 2 looks like -         lines ........................................................................................................                                 g =10

Answer (score 1):

Here are some modifications to your code, which should now work as you want:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

Use a lexically scoped 3 argument open (which is now recommended practise):

```
open my $file1, '<', '1.txt' or die "Cannot open file\n";
open my $file2, '<', '2.txt' or die "Cannot open file\n";
```

Then add each of your lines in `file1` to the end of the array `@parts`:

```
my @parts;
push @parts, $_ while(<$file1>);    
chomp(@parts);
```

Then simply read `file2` line by line and substitute appropriately, then you can see what's happened to each line by printing each line (`$_`) to STDOUT:

```
while (<$file2>) {
    chomp;
     s/threshold1/$parts[0]/;
     s/threshold2/$parts[1]/;
     s/threshold3/$parts[2]/; # I assume you want '30' here?
     print  "$_\n";
}
```

So the output is:

```
a=1 b=2 c=3
d=4 e=5 f=6
g = 10 h=7 i=8
lines
lines
j= 9 k=11 
l = 20
lines
lines
m = 30
lines
lines
```

Let me know if this is indeed what you're trying to do and I can explain the changes I've made

Comment: @fugu...this code is working perfectly...but data is not replaced in file2....It shows changes on command prompt

Comment: @Suhan That's good! I'm going to let you figure out how to print to a file by yourself

Comment: @fugu..I am able to save it in new file but what about the replacing and saving in old file....One more thing I have posted one more query in which code works fine but output not printed can you look into that..thanks

Comment: Why do you want to replace the old file? That's generally quite a dangerous thing to do. See answer to your new question

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are reading lines from both files and processing them in pairs. So line one of the data file will take values from line one of the threshold file, line two from line two of the threshold file etc. And the loop will end when you reach the third line of both files because there is no more data in the threshold file

This program will do what you need. It reads all the values in `data1.txt` into the array `@thresholds` and pulls the contents of the file `data2.txt` into scalar `$data`. Then strings matching the regex pattern `threshold\d+` are replaced with one of the elements of `@threshold` by subtracting one from the number at the end of the string and using it as an index into the array. so `threshold1` is replaced by `$threshold[0]`, `threshold2` by `$threshold[1]` etc. It finally reopens the data file for output and writes the modified string into it

The program expects the paths to the two files as parameters on the command line, so it should be run as `perl thresh_replace.pl data1.txt data2.txt`

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use v5.10.1;
use autodie;

my ($thresholds_file, $data_file) = @ARGV;

my @thresholds = do {
    open my $fh, '<', $thresholds_file;
    local $/;
    split ' ', <$fh>;
};

my $data = do {
    open my $fh, '<', $data_file;
    local $/;
    <$fh>;
};

$data =~ s/threshold(\d+)/$thresholds[$1-1]/g;

{
    open my $fh, '>', $data_file;
    print $fh $data;
}
```

#### output

```
a=1 b=2 c=3
d=4 e=5 f=6
g = 10 h=7 i=8
lines
lines
j= 9 k=11
l = 20
lines
lines
m = 30
lines
lines
```

Answer (score 0):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Tie::File; #This module can use for reading and writing on the same file

my $File1 = "File1.txt";
my $File2 = "File2.txt";

my @array;
tie @array, 'Tie::File', $File2 || die "Error: Couldn't tie the \"$File1\" file: $!";
my $len = join "\n", @array;
open(FILE, $File1) || die "Couldn't open the file $File2: $!\n";

#Threshold and line count matches
my $lineCount = '1';
while(<FILE>)
{
    my $line = $_;
    if($line!~/^$/) { chomp($line);

    #Replace threshold with the first file values
    $len=~s/threshold$lineCount/$line/i; }
    $lineCount++;
}
@array = split/\n/, $len;
untie @array;
close(FILE);
```